# Jquery Count where checkbox checked and parent display block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count, hidden

I have to count multiple elements.
It's necessary to check, if the checkbox is checked and the parent div isn't hidden (display: none;)

I tried multiple things but couldn't find a solution.

My last tests were these:
Javascript

```
function triggerCounter() {
  countAll = $('.form-border').filter(function() {
    return $(this).css('display') !== 'none';
  }).length;
  countFilled = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).prop('checked') == true && $(this).parent().css('display') !== 'none' );
  }).length;

  countPerc = (countFilled*100)/countAll;
  $('#progressbar').css('width', countPerc + '%');
  $('#progressText').text(countFilled + ' / ' + countAll);
}
```

The Problem is this snippet:

```
countFilled = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function() {
    return ($(this).prop('checked') == true && $(this).parent().css('display') !== 'none' );
}).length;
```

And the HTML is looking like this: (this will not be counted)

```
<div class="form-border transition-2" style="display: none;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p class="form-header">Bundesland</p>
        <p class="form-answer">
        <select id="EF3" name="EF3" class="form-select-style form-input-style">
            <option value="1">Test</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
        <input type="checkbox" name="deleteEF3" id="deleteEF3" class="form-delete-checkbox" checked="checked">
    </div>
</div>
```

(this is counted)

```
<div class="form-border transition-2">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <p class="form-header">Bundesland</p>
        <p class="form-answer">
        <select id="EF2" name="EF2" class="form-select-style form-input-style">
            <option value="1">Test</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
        <input type="checkbox" name="deleteEF2" id="deleteEF2" class="form-delete-checkbox" checked="checked">
    </div>
</div>
```

The Result for this is always 2 and not 1..

I hope you can help me with this problem!

Greets.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrqy6qt/3/

Comment: why don't you just check if `input:checked:visible`?

Comment: because the parent div isn't visible. so input:checked:visible is not working correctly.. unhappily

Comment: [have you tried it?](https://jsfiddle.net/dm3wg5nL/)

Comment: yes. the result for `countFilled = $('input:checked:visible').length;` is 0. Also for your code

Comment: Visible has changed since jQuery v.3, should work with prior versions. Which one you use? You can also use `$('div:visible > input[type=checkbox]:checked'` -> that **has** to work in any version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure that `$(this)` in the filter function is referring to the element.

try changing your filter function to

```
  countFilled = $('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function(i,element) {
      return ($(element).prop('checked') == true && $(element).parent().height() > 0 );
  }).length;
```

Comment: The Result is now 0 instead of 1.
This is frustrating ☹
But thank you anyway!

Comment: Now it's again 2/1 ^^
You can check it here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwrqy6qt/2/)

Comment: It might be because you are using the same id for multiple elements - id should be unique

Comment: in the life-system they are. I just forget to edit it in this example ^^ i'm sorry for that.

Comment: its because both div's are on display 'block', the display 'none' is on an higher div - if you will check the height it should work... edited the answer again

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it is easy to select a checked checkbox which is a child element of a visible div:

```
$('div:visible > input[type=checkbox]:checked');
```

Please note, there has been a crucial change on [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector, since the version 3 was released:

> jQuery 3 slightly modifies the meaning of :visible (and therefore of
>   :hidden). Starting with this version, elements will be considered
>   :visible if they have any layout boxes, including those of zero width
>   and/or height. For example, br elements and inline elements with no
>   content will be selected by the :visible selector.